# Localizing String with placement holders in Swift

Tags: swift, string, localization

Using Swift 3, deployment target iOS 9 or 10. Tested this on both.

Why does:

```
    let s = "8 août 2017" 
    let sUtf8 = (s as NSString).utf8String!
    let template = "%1$s"
    let s1 = String(format: template, arguments: [sUtf8])
    NSLog(s1)
    let s2 = String.localizedStringWithFormat(template,((s as NSString).utf8String)!)
    NSLog(s2)
```

log "8 ao√ªt 2017" instead of "8 août 2017"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the Apple's documentation of [String Format Specifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1).

> `%s` Null-terminated array of 8-bit unsigned characters. Because **the
>   `%s` specifier causes the characters to be interpreted in the system
>   default encoding**, the results can be variable, especially with
>   right-to-left languages. For example, with RTL, `%s` inserts direction
>   markers when the characters are not strongly directional. For this
>   reason, it’s best to avoid %s and specify encodings explicitly.

(Bold style added.)

There's no guarantee that the passed byte sequence is interpreted as UTF-8.

The UTF-8 byte sequence for `"8 août 2017"` (in hexadecimal):

```
38 20 61 6f c3 bb 74 20 32 30 31 37
```

If your device's default encoding is set to ISO-Latin1, the bytes are interpreted as:

(The system default encodings may be different in users' devices.)

```
8     a  o  √  ª  t     2  0  1  7
```

Generally useful guideline: **Never use `%s` in your Swift code.**

---

In Swift code, use `%@` instead. (I recommend to use `%@` in Objective-C as far as possible.)

```
let s = "8 août 2017"
let template = "%1$@"
let s1 = String(format: template, s)
NSLog(s1) //->8 août 2017
let s2 = String.localizedStringWithFormat(template, s)
NSLog(s2) //->8 août 2017
```

You have no need to use ugly and risky(*) `(s as NSString).utf8String`.

---

(*) The lifetime of C-string region for `.utf8String` may be *shorter than the string object*. And, in Swift, the lifetime of *the string object* may be far shorter than that in Objective-C.

Comment: Thanks a million! I would have never found that without your help! I was looking more to the %S specifier but couldn't manage to get an utf16 array from a String.

As a small remark: it should be String(format: template, [s]) ... but I started using the String.localizedStringWithFormat ... instead which doesn't need the array.

Comment: @KristofVanLandschoot, Happy to hear my answer could be some help of you. By the way it should be `String(format: template, s)` or `String(format: template, arguments: [s])` in Swift. `String(format: template, [s])` causes no compile-time errors, but may generate unexpected result.